# Wordpress hierarchical dropdown

Tags: wordpress

We would like a hierarchical dropdown on a form to show the term names of a taxonomy called areas. The users first selects a category and gets taken to the form page - we get the dropdown to show the term names but it is from all the posts - we just want the term names from areas that is within the selected category.

Comment: Maybe you're better of with this question at wordpress.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would help, but I generally try to condense my forms as much as possible. I like this jQuery plugin, and I've used it several times:

[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Description from the site:

> Chosen is a JavaScript plugin that makes long, unwieldy select boxes much more user-friendly. It is currently available in both jQuery and Prototype flavors.

You can use it with the  tag to create your Parent Category / Term names list, and allow people to quickly get to the term name they want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, not exactly what we are looking for. We just need our wordpress query to filter taxonomy terms by selected category.